# Laravel 5.4 Queue Email

Tags: php, laravel, queue, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to use Laravel Queues for sending emails using the database driver, I have already configured it, run the migration for the "jobs" table and when I run this:

`Mail::to($user->email)->queue(new CompraRealizadaAdmin(Cart::content(), $monto_descuento, $envio, $user_array, $direccion, $compra));`

A record is added on the "jobs" table, but, how do I run the queue on the database table?, I understand that for triggering it at the moment it is added, I will need to run the command `php artisan queue:listen`, or if I need to run all the ones that are still on queue, I will use `php artisan queue:work`.

But how do I run the command without the need to open terminal and keep it open until it has finished...?

I had the idea of creating a schedule and run it every minute and just execute the code: `Artisan::call('queue:work');` but that does not work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, preferences and your target OS you can use

- [supervisord](http://supervisord.org) (cross platform)
- [upstart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upstart) / [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) (linux)
- [launchd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchd) (OS X)

or alike services to manage your queue worker processes.

In fact Laravel documentation explains in great detail [how to install and configure supervisord](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues#supervisor-configuration) for this.

Comment: I just need to send various emails after a process but they need to run asynchronously since it is a purchase process. Is there another way?

Comment: Queues is exactly the way to go. What is the problem with installing `supervisord`?

Comment: I don't have permissions on the server I'm working with to install it... if I dispatch it as a Job, will it do it async?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which OS you are working on for Ubuntu or linux you can use `supervisor` and `hup`.

butt be careful you have to run `hup` every time you reboot your machine.

thats how you can run this command. `hup php artisan queue:work`.

Hope this helps